# How to define a macro with an indefinite amount of arguments inside another macro?

Tags: rust

This works, but `test_macro` accepts only one argument:

```
macro_rules! test_define (
    ($name:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $name (
            ( $x:expr ) => (
                // something
            )
        );
    )
);

test_define!(test_macro);
```

If I try and do this:

```
macro_rules! test_define2 (
    ($name:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $name (
            ( $($x:expr),* ) => (
                // something
            )
        );
    )
);

test_define2!(test_macro2);
```

Compilation fails with:

```
error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |             ( $($x:expr),* ) => (
  |                ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known bug that [nested macros don't allow repetitions in binding patterns (issue #35853)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35853).

Unfortunately, there is no workaround. The only solution is to change your API to not rely on repetition inside nested macros.

Comment: @Shepmaster OK removed the version. (BTW fixing this will require changing syntax => requires FCP/RFC => even if someone implements it this won't land on master soon)

Comment: Oh, I recognize that. My point was mostly around making definitive statements about versions of software that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 3):

While it is not possible to do this directly, as [kennytm described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720185/8159982), you could do this using [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html)(*in case you really need to, otherwise I would not recommend it*).
While it's probably a lot simpler when using [`nightly`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.13.0/book/nightly-rust.html), it is also possible in `stable`.

## Limitations

Please tell me in case I missed anything or in case there might be problems when using [custom derive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720185/8159982) like this in the future.

- You need to create a struct, which causes one of the following problems

  1. there is either a maximum of 1 macro call per module
  2. the user is required to add another string of characters when calling the outer macro
  3. you create a private module which contains the required struct and could be accessed

---

So let's just copy the example from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html), and just look at this part of the code:

```
fn impl_hello_world(ast: &syn::DeriveInput) -> quote::Tokens {
    let name = &ast.ident;
    quote! {
        impl HelloWorld for #name {
            fn hello_world() {
                println!("Hello, World! My name is {}", stringify!(#name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

inside of the `quote!` macro, you are not limited to the implementation of the `struct`. you could change this to

```
quote! {
    macro_rules! #name {
         ($($expr:expr),*) => {
         // something
         }
    }
}
```

now you have a macro with the same name as a `struct` which takes an infinite amount of arguments.

To do this in another macro, the outer macro just has to look like this:

```
macro_rules! test_define {
    ($name:ident) => {
        #[allow(non_camel_case_types)] // because macro names are lower case
        #[allow(dead_code)] // because this struct should never be used
        #[derive(HelloWorld)]
        struct $name { }
    }
};
```

And now you can call `test_define` and then the inner macro:

```
test_define!(foo);

fn main() {
    foo!()
}
```

---

However, there is still one problem: people could accidentally access your struct. So there are ways to circumvent this(each solution is a directly linked the problem with the same number):

1. name the struct in a way which prevents accidental access by pure chance:

   ```
   macro_rules! test_define {
       ($name:ident) => {
           #[allow(dead_code)]
           #[derive(HelloWorld)]
           struct Dgfggsdfgujksdsdsdfsdfsdg { 
               $name: u8,
           }
       }
   };
   ```

   You have to change your [proc macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/first-edition/procedural-macros.html) to use the `struct field` instead of `name` inside of `quote!` and in case the `test_define!` is called more than once in the same crate you have 2 structs with identical names which causes a compile time error.
2. to prevent two identical struct names you could also change `test_define!` to take an additional argument:

   ```
   macro_rules! test_define {
       ($name:ident, $rep_guard:ident) => {
           #[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
           #[allow(dead_code]
           #[derive(HelloWorld)]
           struct $rep_guard { 
               $name: u8,
           }
       }
   };
   ```

   You are using a `struct field` instead of the `name` with this method. To use you now have to write `test_define!(foo,fvgfdgdfgdfgd)`, which is really awkward, so I would not recommend this.
3. This is probably the best option, now you can keep your strange `struct` name from *solution 1* and just put the whole thing in a `module`. Meaning that no one can accidentally access the created struct and you can have an infinite amount of calls to `test_define!`.

   ```
   macro_rules! test_define {
       ($name:ident) => {
           #[macro_use] // to use the macro in the current module
           mod $name {
               #[allow(dead_code)]
               #[derive(HelloWorld)]
               struct Dgfggsdfgujksdsdsdfsdfsdg { 
                   $name: u8,
               }
           }
       }
   };
   ```

---

The compiler should simply remove all of those structs, as they are `dead_code`
(at least when building with the `--release` flag). You could adapt the `quote!` by adding `#[macro_export]` if you need it.

Another advantage is that proc macros use your source code in the same way as a `String` or as `Tokens` which can be cast to a `String`, this means that you could create multiple macros, for example:

`test_derive!(foo)` =>  `foo!()`, `foo_with_var!(75)`

In case there is anything you don't understand, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can define arbitrary meta macros if you get the parent macro to write the outer `$` signs. A way to do it is to pass a `$` in your parent macro and store it in a variable so you can use it later.

For you can define `test_define2` as follow:

```rust
macro_rules! test_define2 (
    (($dollar:tt) $name:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $name (
            ( $dollar($x:expr),* ) => (
                // something
            )
        );
    );
);
```

Calling it like this:

```rust
test_define2(($) test_macro2);
```

will expand to:

```rust
macro_rules! test_macro2 (
    ( $($x:expr),* ) => (
        ($($x),*) // or something
    )
);
```

Which works as expected.
To avoid having to add the extra `($)` when calling meta macros you can write a second macro that call the meta macro with the added symbol or if it is possible, add this final match arm:

```rust
macro_rules! test_define2 (
    (($d:tt) $name:ident) => (
        macro_rules! $name (
            ( $d($x:expr),* ) => (
                ($d($x),*) // or something
            )
        );
    );
    ($($t:tt)+) => (
        // parenthesis or curly braces are necessary to properly "escape" the $
        test_define2!(($) $($t)+);
    );
);

// test_define2!(test_macro2);
// expands to:
// test_define2!(($)test_macro2);
// expands to:
// macro_rules!test_macro2(
//   ($($x:expr),*) => (
//     ($($x),*) // or something
//   )
// );
```